# Is there a shortcut in VS Code to implement a jest todo test?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jestjs

When I have:

```
test.todo('customer can order a pizza');
```

I would like a shortcut that would transform the line to:

```
test('customer can order a pizza', async () => {
  <|>
});
```

where `<|>` is the cursor position.

Is it possible using snippets? Ideally, I would prefer not to have to select the whole line before triggering the transform.

Or is there an extension that does this?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the extension [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command)

```
{
    "key": "alt+x",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": { 
        "sequence": [
            "cursorEnd",
            "cursorHomeSelect",
            { "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
              "args": {
                "snippet": "test(${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/test\\.todo('[^']+');/'${1}'/}, async () => {\\n\\t$0\\n\\t});"
              }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check jest snippets to vscode https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=andys8.jest-snippets

Answer (score 0):

Based on [answer from @rioV8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72115854/3995091), I was able to make it work   thanks a ton

Open `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` from command palette, and paste:

```json
  {
    "key": "cmd+shift+i",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": {
      "sequence": [
        "cursorEnd",
        "cursorHomeSelect",
        {
          "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
          "args": {
            "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(test|it)\\.todo\\(('[^']+'|\"[^\"]+\")\\);/$1($2/}, async () => {\n\t$1\n});"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I chose `cmd+shift+i` for "implement", feel free to choose which ever shortcut you like.